# How figure out server requirement for PUT request?

Tags: c#, request, httpwebrequest, put

It's about 1 year that i work on **webRequest**. I'm using C# language and for doing my job i use HttpWebRequest/Response.
I use HttpWebRequest class because you should set properties, control cookies and for sure use tools like Fiddler so that way i learn more instead of just using webClient class.

## Q:

So now this question blowing my mind that how an application should know, what proper data they should send during POST request to accept by server?

Ok let's me explain more. Imagine you wanna send some information to www.abc.com from your application. So you know that this site accept POST request but how you send your data, in Multipart/form-data or application/x-www-form-urlencoded format? should you set any headers or not? and etc.

Tools like Fiddler are just capturing the package between UserAgent and server. So they just show us what properties set in packages.[as John Saunders told in comment]

Comment: I'm really unsure what you're asking. Browsers post what they are told to post. They don't "know" anything. You're also wrong about Fiddler. It just shows what the client sends and what the server sends back. It knows nothing about what _should_ be sent.

Comment: It's great you spent a long time making this question, but, like John, I have no idea what you are asking!

Comment: I seen site that force you to specify some properties, or proper content-body during POST request to accept your request otherwise they reject it. So im asking how browsers know these things? (sry for my bad english)

Comment: @John Saunders you are right about fiddler and browsers. Let me see if I've got it or not; browsers use form tag attribute to figure out how they should send data to server properly, am i right?

Comment: They use several form tag attributes to decide this, yes, or else they are told the equivalent information via JavaScript.

Comment: @John Saunders Ok so if a program doesn't use html forms to send data, how it should know to send data in proper format? thx.

Comment: The program doesn't know. The programmer has to know. That means that the programmer has to be told what format to use.

Comment: @John Saunders thanks a lot. I don't have too much information about APIs but can such information provide by API documents for other programmers?

Comment: They are hopefully provided by API documents, or other documentation. This information is never known by the browser ahead of time.